# how can I copy the tables schema from database to another database using SqlserverCe in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-ce

I want to copy the sqlserverCe database(.sdf) tables into another sqlserverCe database(.sdf) in the same application in ASP.NET.

Is it possible? If possible, please help me how can I do this?

Comment: Just schema or schema and data?

Comment: Hi thank you for giving response i want copy the schema only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use my scripting library, which can script entire schema to a file, and run the script using the ExecuteSql method against the other sdf file. http://exportsqlce.codeplex.com

Comment: Hi,actually i have create a one template database(template.sdf "it has table of schema only no data") it has the tables,when a user login then create one new database and add the tables from template.sdf to user.sdf database.

Comment: Then cant you just copy template.sdf and rename it to user.sdf?

Comment: because it is default database for every user not only for one user.

Comment: so create COPY for every user. For example for user1 copy template.sdf to user1.sdf...for user2 copy template.sdf to user2.sdf. Code: File.Copy("template.sdf", "user1.sdf") you will have template.sdf and user1.sdf after this.

Comment: after copying file how can i store that user.sdf file in serverpath App_data